# Differentiating while two variables are changing together

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

$MRS = \frac{u_1}{u_2}$

Differentiating with respect to $x_1$:

the book shows that you get 
$$\frac{u_2\bigl( u_{11}+u_{12}\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}\bigr) - u_1\bigl( u_{21}+u_{22}\frac{dx_2}{dx_1}\bigr)}{u_2^2}.$$

I didn't understand how the book found this?

Here, $u_{11}$ is the second order partial derivative of the utility function with respect to $x_1$

This is the logic behind the notation of other partial derivatives. This is so since there are two goods: $x_1$ and $x_2$. The economic logic is that when we are accounting changes in the utility function with respect to good 1, there are changes in good 2 which also needs to be taken into account.

To give some more context, this is Marginal rate of substitution in economics and we are doing the second order condition.

$u_1 is the Marginal utility of good 1. Similarly for the other one. 
In economics, marginal utility is found by differentiating utility.

The first equation in the quetion (MRS) is found by:

$u_1dx_1 + u_2dx_2 = 0$

From here MRS = $dx_2/dx_1 =  [u_1/u_2]$

(This is in absolute value form)

Comment: I am having great difficulty parsing your question.  It would be helpful if you reviewed the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and corrected your formatting.

Comment: Hi, yes this is corrected now. Sorry for the initial inconvenience.

Comment: Could you clarify what $u_{ij}$ is?

Comment: That is the trouble I'm facing as well. Is it some standard math notation while differentiating?

Comment: What is the definition of $u_1$ and $u_2$, the book had to define those at some point.  Also the book should have defined $x_1$ and $x_2$, or some "parent" variable $x$.  From our point of view there is not enough context to answer

Comment: I have added additional remarks. Please check.

Comment: What exactly is your question? So far, you have not asked any specific thing? You've only made statements.

Comment: I didn't understand how the book shows the second step.

Comment: @user585380 That's the quotient rule. The only mystery is that they've made some substitution for the derivatives of $u_1$ and $u_2$ by some earlier calculation, or they made some assumptions about what the independent variables are. So, please check. What variables do $u_1$ and $u_2$ depend on?

Comment: Looks to me like the subscripts on $u$ indicate partial derivatives. That’s a more-or-less standard notation.

Comment: @amd Yes! Got it now. Why was I so puzzled. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

(edit: I answered before I see your edit on the question, so my answer was about how we derive the MRS).

The marginal rate of substitution is the slope of the indifference curve which represents the utility gained from bundles of, usually, two goods, $$u(x_1, x_2)$$
As usually the two goods are substitutes; to get one more unit from one good you have to give up "some" units of the other good. 
In other words, MRS is the ratio between the marginal utility of both goods.
$$MRS= -{MU_1\over MU_2}$$

The marginal utility of good 1 is the change in the utility with respect to $\text{$x_1$}$:
$$MU_1 = \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x_1} = \frac{u (x_1 + \Delta x_1, x_2) - u(x_1,x_2)}{\Delta x_1}$$
$$MU_1 = {∂ \, u(x_1,x_2)\over ∂ \, x_1}$$
And you can do the same for good 2; the partial derivative with respect to $\text{$x_2$}$:
$$MU_2 = {\partial \, u(x_1,x_2)\over \partial \, x_2}$$

Or, we can consider the indifference curve as a relationship so that we can express the value of good 2 as a function of good 1:
$$x_2= x_2(x_1)$$
$$∴ u (x_1, x_2(x_1))=a \quad {\{a \in \Bbb R \, \vert \, a \gt 0\}}$$

Differentiate it with respect to $\text{$x_1$}$:
$${\partial u(x_1,x_2(x_1))\over \partial x_1} + {\partial u(x_1,x_2(x_1))\over \partial x_2}{dx_2(x_1)\over dx_1}=0$$
$${dx_2(x_1)\over dx_1} = - {{\partial u(x_1,x_2(x_1))\over \partial x_1}\over {\partial u(x_1,x_2(x_1))\over \partial x_2}} = -{MU_1\over MU_2}$$